# undefined reference of an extern variable when using cmake

Tags: c, cmake, kdevelop

I have the following c files.

prog1.h

```
#ifndef PROG1_H
#define PROG1_H
extern char* hello;
#endif
```

prog1.c

```
#include "prog1.h"

char *hello="hello";
```

one.c

```
#include "prog1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("%s", hello);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(tester)

add_executable(main one.c)
add_executable(prog1 prog1.c)
```

On attempt of building the project "tester" in KDevelop I get the following output.

[output log generated in KDevelop on building the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5bxe.png)

But when I compile the file explicitly on terminal by the command -

> gcc one.c prog1.c -o outputfile

it returns me the "outputfile" which on running -

> ./outputfile

i get the desired output

```
akash@Z50-70:~/projects/Tester$ gcc one.c prog1.c -o outputfile
akash@Z50-70:~/projects/Tester$ ./outputfile
hello
akash@Z50-70:~/projects/Tester$
```

Can anyone help me out with the issue i am facing while trying to build the project in KDevelop?

Comment: You're telling cmake to build two different executables. Please check the docs.

Comment: You should post the error message instead of linking to a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something to do with KDevelop. It is about your `CMakeLists.txt`. `cmake` is used as the project manager in KDevelop and CLion. But your question is not specific to an IDE.

The error says undefined reference to main because you are compiling `prog1.c` as an executable. and an executable should have a main function. `prog1.c` doesn't have one.

You are adding two different executables. add two sources in a single executable.

```
add_executable(main one.c prog1.c)
```

Surely you can have multiple executables in a single project. However in general the project name is set as the executable name if you are producing a single executable only unless you have a special requirement.

```
add_executable(tester one.c prog1.c)
```